# Interface dinâmica em Typescript Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, front-end, interface

Olá! Estou criando uma aplicação de cadastro que deve realizar vários tipos de cadastro. Para cada tipo de cadastro terei um formulário com campos diferentes. Como a chamada para o service é exatamente igual para todos os formulários e só deve mudar o objeto Cadastro que eu envio para o service (e consequentemente para a API) pensei em criar uma interface dinâmica. Pensando que em um tipo de cadastro posso ter os campos 'nome_cliente', 'cidade_cliente' e em outros não, pensei em criar algo assim:

```
export interface Cadastro {
nome_cliente?: string,
cidade_cliente?: string, 
tipo_veiculo?: string
}
```

que teria todos os campos de todos os formulários mas entenderia quando eu não passasse algum desses campos. E meu service estaria esperando por essa interface. Mas me pergunto se isso não prejudica o desempenho 'ficar usando ? em todos os campos' e se existe uma forma melhor de eu fazer isso sem precisar ficar replicando a chamada do meu service.

Comment: Melhor usar interfaces extensíveis para maior organização e flexibilidade do código. Herdando de uma base, novas interfaces expandem funcionalidades, facilitando manutenção e reutilização.